# Русские буквы в программе

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  string str;int i;
  cin >> str;

  for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() - 1; i++)
  {
    if ( str[i] == 'd' ) str[i] = 'в';
  }
  cout << str[i];
  system("PAUSE");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

В чем проблема? Это из-за того, что я русские буквы использую, поэтому???

Comment: @navi1893, а в чем проблема??? 

Что именно Вы видите и считаете это проблемой? А что Вы ожидали увидеть?

Comment: @avp он просто зачем то выходил из программы, ничего не делая. Но проблема решена. Просто щас я там пишу если ввел я 'd', тогда вывести 'в', но она мне зачем то 'т' выводит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale( LC_ALL,"Russian" );
    //string str;int i; //Вам места жалко ???
    string str;
    //int i;    //Вы уверены что вам нужна эта переменная ???

    //Уведомляем юзера о том чего же мы от него хотим
    cout << "Please Input Text: ";

    //cin >> str;   //Как вы себе это представляете ? Может всетаки как то так:
    getline(std::cin, str);

    cout << "This you entered: " << str << endl;

    //for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() - 1; i++) //зачем так жить ?
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)  
    {
        if ( str[i] == 'd' ) str[i] = 'в';
    }

    //cout << str[i]; //Вам точно нужно напечатать только последний символ ?
    cout << "After the action: " << str << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: спасибо! А почему я написал if 'd' вывести 'в', а он выводит мне 'т'??? @lirik90

Comment: Да и еще, весь этот вылет был из за чего? Вроде ошибок же нет, кроме str.length() - 1

Comment: Ну каким же боком ошибок нет, там каждая строчка это ошибка

Comment: Еще setlocale( LC_ALL,"Russian" ); ...напиши что бы 'в' выводил

Comment: Не работало, потому что нет такого определения оператора >> для cin которое бы могло вывод потока запихнуть сразу в класс string

Comment: @lirik90, **дезинформируете** доверчивого @navi1893

>нет такого определения оператора >> для cin которое бы могло вывод потока запихнуть сразу в класс string

Оператор `cin >> s;` для `string s;` **читает очередное слово** из потока
(аналогично формату `"%s" в  char s[BUFSIZE]; scanf ("%s",s);`)

Comment: @lirik90 setlocale( LC_ALL,"ruRU.UTF-8" ); или "ruRU". "Russian" нестандартно,  написанная изначально в книге, где автор все проверял на _теперь_ очень старом альт-линукс.